# Can't send push notifications with PubNub SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

I'm implementing push notifications in my app using the PubNub SDK for iOS. My build target is 9.0.

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4), but I can't get it to work and I feel I need some more information to understand the concept. Take a look at what I've done so far:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic) PubNub *client;

@end
```

in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function, I run this code to set up push notifications:

```
/* push notifications */
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%s with error: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
}
```

The tutorial posts code like this, is this supposed to go in the delegate or other ViewControllers?:

```
PNConfiguration *configuration = [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:@"demo"
                                                              subscribeKey:@"demo"];
self.client = [PubNub clientWithConfiguration:configuration];
[self.client addPushNotificationsOnChannels:@[@"wwdc",@"google.io"] 
                     withDevicePushToken:self.devicePushToken
                           andCompletion:^(PNAcknowledgmentStatus *status) {

 // Check whether request successfully completed or not.
 if (!status.isError) {

    // Handle successful push notification enabling on passed channels.
 }
 // Request processing failed.
 else {

    // Handle modification error. Check 'category' property to find out possible issue because
    // of which request did fail.
    //
    // Request can be resent using: [status retry];
 }
 }];
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface MessagingViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) PubNub *client;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *devicePushToken;

@end

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSData *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DeviceToken"];
if (deviceToken)
{
    self.devicePushToken = deviceToken;
    PNConfiguration *configuration = [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:publishKey
                                                                     subscribeKey:subscribeKey];
    self.client = [PubNub clientWithConfiguration:configuration];
    [self.client addPushNotificationsOnChannels:@[self.senderId]
                            withDevicePushToken:self.devicePushToken
                                  andCompletion:^(PNAcknowledgmentStatus *status) {

                                      // Check whether request successfully completed or not.
                                      if (!status.isError) {

                                          // Handle successful push notification enabling on passed channels.
                                      }
                                      // Request processing failed.
                                      else {

                                          // Handle modification error. Check 'category' property to find out possible issue because
                                          // of which request did fail.
                                          //
                                          // Request can be resent using: [status retry];
                                      }
                                  }];
}
}
```

Code I'm using to send a notification:

```
            /* send push notifications */
        [self.client publish:nil toChannel:self.senderId mobilePushPayload: @{@"aps": @{@"message":message}}
              withCompletion:^(PNPublishStatus *status) {

                  // Check whether request successfully completed or not.
                  // if (status.isError) // Handle modification error.
                  // Check 'category' property to find out possible issue because
                  // of which request did fail. Request can be resent using: [status retry];
              }];
```

Could someone explain and give me sort of an overview or where the different parts of the code belongs and what is required?

Answer (score 0):

Good day Erik,

All code is valid except dictionary passed to *mobilePushPayload* parameter. Passed dictionary should in case of Apple Push Notifications conform to described [specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW10) for it. There is no *message* key in APNS payload, there at least should be *alert* and string value for it.

So, if you want to publish, you should try something like this:

```html
[self.client publish:nil toChannel:self.senderId mobilePushPayload: @{@"aps": @{@"alert":message}}
      withCompletion:^(PNPublishStatus *status) {

    // Check whether request successfully completed or not.
    // if (status.isError) // Handle modification error.
    // Check 'category' property to find out possible issue because
    // of which request did fail. Request can be resent using: [status retry];
}];
```

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: I see, thanks! Also, should the addPushNotificationsOnChannels call be made within the app delegate?

Comment: @Erik this method should be called every time, when you get device push token. Because only application delegate respond on this even directly, we suggest to do it there.

Comment: I understand. So when I want to send a push notification to a specific user, I could send it to a channel with an ID that is equivalent to the ID of the user for instance? These channels are kind of notification groups?

Comment: @Erik, if you want to send notification to particular user, that user should have unique _channel_ name on which push notifications has been enabled with `-addPushNotificationsOnChannels:withDevicePushToken:andCompletion:` method. When proper dictionary passed into `-publish:toChannel:mobilePushPayload:withCompletion:` for _mobilePushPayload_ parameter, **PubNub** service will send push notification to user, which registered to receive updates on _channel_ which is passed during _publish_ API call.

Comment: @Erik Channels is real-time data stream units, any JSON-compatible data can be passed through it. In case if _mobilePushPayload_ has been provided, **PubNub** service will take additional step and send notification to all who registered with specified _channel_ name.

Comment: I've configured it as such now, and the PubNub dashboard messages do change. However, no push notifications are displayed when I send - any idea why?

Comment: @Erik just to ensure, did you enabled _Push notifications_ add-on on page of [admin panel](https://admin.pubnub.com)? If you passed all steps, then it shouldn't be an issue and valid dev APNS certificate has been uploaded to PubNub admin portal and add-on enabled.   There is a way to debug what is going on when message is published with mobile payload described [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4#advanced_troubleshooting_enabling_advanced_debug).

Comment: @Erik I am also facing the same issue but for different cause. I am not able to register the channel for Push with other device when app is in background. Lets say UserA & UserB wants to communicate then we create new roomId, but how UserB will register for Push with his device token ?

Comment: @Praveen-K actually your question not related to this issue and more about application design. To share somehow information from UserA to UserB you can use channel names which is based on receiver identifier (nickname, real name). Knowing this channel for target person you can send there identifier or invitation to communicate along with channel identifier. Using this information UserB can subscribe on notification (but UserB should have application in foreground to receive invitation).